# Tensorflow Data Input Toggle: Train/Validation

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have data that comes into my graph through queue runners, after I switched from the handy but speed-inferior placeholders.

After each training epoch, I wish to run a validation pass. Other than the the training pass, the validation pass uses different data, no augmentation and no shuffling.

The question is simple: how do I toggle these things?

A few observations:

- I cannot toggle the `shuffle` option in the `string_input_producer` through a `tf.placeholder` boolean.
- The only examples on-the-line that I have found use the `placeholder` to seperate the training from the validation data. These in turn, do not use the superior queue runners.
- I did manage to do the above with a `tf.cond()` here i would test for a `is_training` `tf.placeholder` boolean that i pass through the `feed_dict`. Is this solution the most optimal? How expensive is this `tf.conf()` method?

Comment: [`tf.cond` is not the solution.](https://groups.google.com/a/tensorflow.org/forum/#!msg/discuss/mLrt5qc9_uU/sGNbC7GpAwAJ)

It pulls things through both queues, on each evaluation of either side.

Comment: `tf.cond` can still be used but with a hack. An alternative is `QueueBase.from_list`. See: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2514 - sigh..

Answer (score 3):

The method that works well for me is to use `tf.placeholder_with_default`:

> ```
> images_train, labels_train = train_data_pipeline(fnlist_train, ref_grid)
> images_val, labels_val = val_data_pipeline(fnlist_val, ref_grid)
> images = tf.placeholder_with_default(images_train, shape=[None, FLAGS.nx_image, FLAGS.ny_image, FLAGS.nz_image])
> labels = tf.placeholder_with_default(labels_train, shape=[None, label_length])
> ```

During training, `images` and `labels` come directly from the training queue. For the intermittent validation steps I feed `images` and `labels` through a feed_dict in a call to`sess.run()`. The only slight hack is that is that the validation data are also tensors from a queue and feed_dict doesn't accept tensors, so I call `sess.run([images_val, labels_val])` first to get numpy values and then use them in the feed_dict. Seems to work well and there is minimal delay from the tensor==>numpy==>tensor conversion, which only occurs during validation anyway.

And for your case where the validation data have separate processing requirements, this can be handled when you set up the separate validation queue and processing flow to it.

Comment: This should work and it also given as https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2514#issuecomment-223447983. But I dislike the numpy roundtrip; I'm sure we can do better.

Comment: Agreed about the round trip. Please post if you find a better way.

Answer (score 1):

One probable answer is usage of `make_template`
This is outlined in https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/kernel_tests/template_test.py ; It basically says one could do this:

```py
training_input, training_output = ([1., 2., 3., 4.], [2.8, 5.1, 7.2, 8.7])
test_input, test_output = ([5., 6., 7., 8.], [11, 13, 15, 17])

tf.set_random_seed(1234)

def test_line(x):
  m = tf.get_variable("w", shape=[],
                      initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer())
  b = tf.get_variable("b", shape=[],
                      initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer())
  return x * m + b

line_template = template.make_template("line", test_line)

train_prediction = line_template(training_input)
test_prediction = line_template(test_input)

train_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(train_prediction - training_output))
test_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(test_prediction - test_output))

optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.1)
train_op = optimizer.minimize(train_loss)

with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
  initial_test_loss = sess.run(test_loss)
  sess.run(train_op)
  final_test_loss = sess.run(test_loss)

# Parameters are tied, so the loss should have gone down when we trained it.
self.assertLess(final_test_loss, initial_test_loss)
```